# Hopkins-Levitzki Theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a an artinian ring and $M$ a f.g. $R-$module. By Hopkins-Levitzki Theorem, $M$ is an artinian module. I am looking for an example such that according to the conditions above, $M$ is not noetherian. Also an example such that $R$ is not noetherian.

Comment: The funny thing is the Hopkins-Levitzki Theorem says exactly you need for answering your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since $R$ is an artinian ring, it is noetherian (theorem 8.44 [*here*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Oi4x9NznFEUC&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq=A+commutative+Artinian+ring+R+is+Noetherian+Sharp+8.44&source=bl&ots=8GE2yG-973&sig=o8CS3qL_IAIHIg1WvR0HQz2QtHo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JvzaVJLpAYGyU8begpAJ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=A%20commutative%20Artinian%20ring%20R%20is%20Noetherian%20Sharp%208.44&f=false)). so every f.g $R$-module is artinian and noetherian